# Facebook graph API for Live Video is showing on user feed but it is visible to only that user but not public

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I'm using iOS graph API to live the broadcast on Facebook, I can start the live broadcast and I can also see the stream on my Facebook feed/ profile but other users can't even after making it public.

Comment: Most likely your _app_ itself is not set to public yet; check that in app dashboard.

Comment: It is already set to public in app dashboard.

Comment: Did you get the Live Video feature reviewed and approved yet?

Comment: Yes, Application has email, public_profile, publish_actions, user_Friends and Live Video API permission and approved as well.